# Facebook create event

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to create events on Facebook using Facebook connect.  So far, the

```
$appapikey = 'my key here';

$facebook = new Facebook($appapikey, 'my secret here');
$user = $facebook->require_login();
$fapi = $facebook->api_client;

if(!$facebook->api_client->users_hasAppPermission('create_event')){
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">window.open("http://www.facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key='.$appapikey.'&v=1.0&ext_perm=create_event", "Permission");</script>';
    echo'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=javascript:history.back();">';
    exit;
}

$event_info = array();
$event_info['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$event_info['category'] = 8;
$event_info['subcategory'] = 36;
$event_info['host'] = 'Me';
$event_info['location'] = $_POST['location'];
$event_info['email'] = $_POST['email'];
$event_info['phone'] = $_POST['phone'];
$event_info['description'] = $_POST['description'];
$event_info['city'] = $_POST['city'];
if($_POST['start_time_ampm'] == 'PM'){
    $_POST['start_time_hour'] = $_POST['start_time_hour'] + 12;
}
if($_POST['end_time_ampm'] == 'PM'){
    $_POST['end_time_hour'] = $_POST['end_time_hour'] + 12;
}

$event_info['start_time'] = mktime($_POST['start_time_hour'],$_POST['start_time_min'],00,$_POST['start_time_month'],$_POST['start_time_day'],$_POST['start_time_year']); //Converts time to UTC
$event_info['end_time'] = mktime($_POST['end_time_hour'],$_POST['end_time_min'],00,$_POST['end_time_month'],$_POST['end_time_day'],$_POST['end_time_year']);



try{
    echo json_encode($_POST);
    $event_id = $fapi->events_create($event_info);
    $sql = "INSERT into events (EventId) values('$event_id')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("can't select events<br>$sql".mysql_error());
    echo 'Event Created!';
}
```

This all works fine, but the event_id returned is always the same for different events.  When I look in my Facebook account, the event was successfully added, but the id there is totally different.  Any idea what I may be doing wrong?

***I figured out this issue. It was because my database field was set to an int and unfortunately, the Facebook id's were too long.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out this issue. It was because my database field was set to an int and unfortunately, the Facebook id's were too long. I just had to change the field type.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$event_id = $fapi->events_create($event_info);
```

I think you want:

```
$event_id = $facebook->api_client->events_create($event_info);
```

Comment: Well, $fapi is actually 
$fapi = $facebook->api_client;

Comment: it's still returning the same id with that change

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `events_create()` needs to be a JSON-encoded string.  Change this:

```
$event_id = $fapi->events_create($event_info);
```

to this:

```
$event_id = $fapi->events_create(json_encode($event_info));
```

Comment: Tried that too, event gets added successfully, but eventid is still the same